# how to close a hdf5 file

Tags: r, hdf5

I am using the `rhdf5` library to create HDF5 files.

```
h5createFile(myHDF5FileName)
h5createDataset(myHDF5FileName,"myData",storage.mode="double",level=9,dims=length(myData), chunk=10000)
h5write(myData,myHDF5FileName,"myData")
```

Works fine, except that when I tried to delete the physical file Windows 7 tells me that the file is still open in `RStudio`, i.e. the file handle seems to be open in my `RStudio` environment. I checked the `rhdf5` documents - http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/rhdf5/inst/doc/rhdf5.pdf and 
http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/manuals/rhdf5/man/rhdf5.pdf

but I couldn't find any function to close the hdf5 connection.

The manual seems to indicate that there is a `H5Fopen` and  `H5Fclose` function and I tried them too, but I still cannot delete the physical file UNLESS I quit `RStudio`.

There is another function `H5close()`, but when I tried that I get an error `Error: could not find function "H5close"`

Comment: Did you try `f = h5createFile(myHDF5FileName)` [...] `H5Fclose(f)`? `H5close(f)`? `close(f)`?

Comment: @Simon, if I try `f=h5createFile(myHDF5FileName)`, the value of `f` is simply `TRUE`.