# R will not delete a file I have opened with the h5 package

Tags: r, hadoop, hdf5

I have a folder full compressed hdf5 files. I'd like to create a script to cycle through each file, decompress, read certain elements of the hdf5 file and then delete the decompressed file.

I am having problems as R will not delete the hdfs file, giving a permissions error. I have closed the reference to the hdf5 file using the appropriate command, which returns TRUE, but the file can only be deleted after restarting the rsession.

Here is an example,

```
library(h5)

# create an example hdf5 file
file <- h5file("test.hdf5", 'w')

# create some example data.
testvec <- rnorm(10)
testmat <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)
row.names(testmat) <- 1:3
colnames(testmat) <- c("A", "BE", "BU")
letters1 <- paste(LETTERS[runif(45, min = 1, max = length(LETTERS))])
letters2 <- paste(LETTERS[runif(45, min = 1, max = length(LETTERS))])
testarray <- array(paste0(letters1, letters2), c(3, 3, 5))

# write the data to hdf5 file
file["test/testvec"] <- testvec
file["test/testmat"] <- testmat
file["test/testarray"] <- testarray

# close the file reference
closed <- h5close(file)
cat(sprintf('Closed the example file = %i\n', closed))

openedFromDisk <- h5file("test.hdf5")
thedata <- readDataSet(openedFromDisk["test/testarray"])
closed <- h5close(openedFromDisk)
cat(sprintf('Closed the loaded file = %i\n', closed))

#attempt to delete the file
removed <- file.remove("test.hdf5")
cat(sprintf('Deleted the loaded file = %i\n', removed))
```

It is like R or h5 package is locking the file even though the close command returns TRUE. Anybody have any idea how I can rectify? I need to delete the uncompressed file as I have several thousand large files to process and my HDD isnt large enough.

Comment: The culprit is likely to be the internal C code of h5. The package doesn't use the standard connection mechanism of R, so it's quite impossible to manipulate this from within R. I'd report this to the creators of h5, as this looks, feels and smells like a bug.

Comment: I will drop the creator an email, and file a bugreport on github. In between posting I found this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23072210/how-to-close-a-hdf5-file?rq=1) which uses a different package but I guess the same C code, which supports your assumption.

Comment: If it can be of any help: terminating the R session effectively removes the binding to the file, so it can be deleted then. I'd use a bash script for now to automate this, but that's not optimal obviously.